# How to find all dictionary words in a big textfile without delimiters?

Tags: c++, algorithm, full-text-search

Given a big textfile (around 500MB of text) I have to find the number of dictionary words in this file. The dictionary used to check if it's a word is a trie for optimized look up.

For a small input like "racecourse", it should return 6 words because {"race", "course", "racecourse", "a", "our", "ace"} are all words in the dictionary. My current method is not efficient:

[Removed code]

This goes through the string and checks every section like:

r

ra

rac

race

racec

raceco

racecou

racecour

racecours

racecourse

In the next iteration, it will then remove 'r' and repeat again with string "acecourse". I have another trie that prevents duplicate strings from being counted. This is rather inefficient and buggy for the big textfile. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can try this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex

Comment: Maybe you could save time by preprocessing your dictionary. Sort it by length, cross index all dictionary words which are part of longer words. When searching the text, start with long words. For each longword then skip all shorter words which are part of it. Looking at your example it seems that this could get some performance.

Comment: Take a look at the [Trie data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Comment: @Avery I think you will need to add more attributes to a trie node for lookup of all possible dictionary words.

Comment: I am using a trie for the dictionary but what additional attribute would you suggest adding to the trie structure?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this faster. Assuming the dictionary is sorted, you can use binarysearches with start- and end- index. The indexes ensure you search to the minimum for matches in the dictionary. I created indexer objects to keep track and narrow each searchresult. It removes indexers when there is nothing to search for.

Code is C#:

```
        public class Indexer
        {
            public int DictStartIndex { get; set; }
            public int DictEndIndex { get; set; }
            public int CharCount { get; set; }
            public int CharPos { get; set; }
        }

        public class WordDictionaryComparer : IComparer<string>
        {
            public int Compare(string x, string y)
            {
                return x.CompareTo(y);
            }
        }


        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> dictionary = new List<string>() { "race", "course", "racecourse", "a", "our", "ace", "butter", "rectangle", "round" };
            dictionary.Sort();

            List<Indexer> indexers = new List<Indexer>();
            WordDictionaryComparer wdc = new WordDictionaryComparer();
            List<string> wordsFound = new List<string>();

            string line = "racecourse";

            for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
            {
                Indexer newIndexer = new Indexer();
                newIndexer.CharPos = i;
                newIndexer.DictEndIndex = dictionary.Count;
                indexers.Add(newIndexer);
                for (int j = indexers.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)

                {
                    var oneIndexer = indexers[j];
                    oneIndexer.CharCount++;
                    string lookFor = line.Substring(oneIndexer.CharPos, oneIndexer.CharCount);
                    int index = dictionary.BinarySearch(oneIndexer.DictStartIndex, oneIndexer.DictEndIndex - oneIndexer.DictStartIndex, lookFor, wdc);
                    if (index > -1) wordsFound.Add(lookFor);
                    else index = ~index;
                    oneIndexer.DictStartIndex = index;

                    //GetEndIndex
                    string lookEnd = lookFor.Substring(0, lookFor.Length - 1) + (char)(line[i] + 1);
                    int endIndex = dictionary.BinarySearch(oneIndexer.DictStartIndex, oneIndexer.DictEndIndex - oneIndexer.DictStartIndex, lookEnd, wdc);
                    if (endIndex < 0) endIndex = ~endIndex;
                    oneIndexer.DictEndIndex = endIndex;
                    if (oneIndexer.DictEndIndex == oneIndexer.DictStartIndex) indexers.RemoveAt(j);
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: Please, have a look at the answer and mark answered when to your liking.